# I want to write function, which take input as a number and returns array , starting from 1 to number. example N= 4, output = [1,2,3,4]

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to write function, which take input as a number and returns array , starting from 1 to number. example N= 4, output = [1,2,3,4]   here I have wrote function, what's wrong with it?

```
func first(N:Int)->[Int]{     
    var result: Int = []     
    do{     
      var i : Int=1         
      if N > 0 {         
      result.insert(i,atIndex:0)         
      ++i     
      } while i > N     
    return result    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unless this is some kind of exercise, you can use Swift's `stride` for this: `Array(1.stride(through:4, by:1))` or even `Array(1...4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get better results using StackOverflow if you take the time to provide more details in your question. For example, what error(s) are you getting? If it runs, how does it fail?

If you want to write your own function as an exercise (as Alladinian commented while I was writing the below), read on; otherwise, look into the `Array(1...N)` suggestion.

At a quick glance, your line `var result: Int = []` is wrong. You're declaring a variable named `result` to be of type `Int`, but trying to assign an empty array to it. You want `var result: [Int] = []`. This declares the variable as being an *array* of `Int`, instead of just being a single `Int`.

You're also inserting new values into `result` at index `0`, which would effectively reverse the order of the numbers in your array.

You also don't need to specify the type when you declare `i`. You can just write `var i = 1`. You're also re-declaring it in each iteration of your loop, so it'll never increment.

Your use of `>` in your `while` condition is incorrect. You want `<=` ("while i is less than or equal to `N` ...").

You're using `do-while` but in Swift it's `repeat-while`, so you want:

```
var i = 1
repeat {
    //...
    i++
} while i <= N
```

You're also not handling the case where `N` (which should really be lowercase) is less than `1` (it could be `0`, and since `N` is an `Int`, it could be negative). So you should decide whether you hand back an empty array or `nil` (in which case, your return type would be `[Int]?` - an optional).

So:

```
func first(n: Int) -> [Int]? {

    if n >= 1 {

        var result: [Int] = []
        var i = 1
        repeat { result.append(i++) } while i <= n

        return result

    }

    return nil

}
```

Comment: (Yes, there are many ways to skin this particular cat.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for Loop since you have a set number. The While loop is condition based.

```
    func first(N:Int)->[Int]{
    var result = [Int]()
    for var x = N; x > 0; --x {
        result.insert(x,atIndex:0)
        }
        return result
    }

    let num = first(10)

    print(num) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this constructor

```
let array = Array(1...n)
```

If you are looking for errors you are assigning an array to an int here

```
var result: Int = []
```

and you are inserting the new int at index 0 so you will get an array like this [4,3,2,1]

and in your while clause you check if `i > N` which it probably never will be unless you send in N = 0

and there is one too many `}`